# Custom JavaScriptConverter Classes

Tags: javascript, serialization, asp.net-3.5

Does anyone know of decent examples of custom JavaScriptConverter classes?  The MSDN's only example is of one converting a ListItemCollection.  What about custom classes?  What if the custom class has a property of another custom class?  Do we need two converters?  Any references would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only need one converter. The example basically outlines how to use the JavaScript converter for *any* custom class. It doesn't need to be a class that is part of the framework.

It will also work for any properties of a custom class that are themselves a custom class.

JSON views objects as collections of key/value pairs, so the documentation example shows how you should take any properties of your object and put them into Dictionaries (a type of Key/Value pair object). If you need a nested custom type, you can just nest Key/Value pairs inside of your main Key/Value pair collection.

Also, unless you have very specific needs (built-in serialization either won't work, or doesn't output what you want), you should just use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer_members.aspx) class.

```
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
MyCustomObject obj = new MyCustomObject();
string json = serializer.Serialize(obj);

MyCustomObject object2 = serializer.Deserialize<MyCustomObject>(json);
```

That should do what you want in 95% of cases.